# Unable to share multiple images using share sheet Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, visionkit

I am trying to save multiple images scanned using vision kit but only the first image seems to save using the share sheet. How do I rectify this issue.

**Saving the image after scanning**

```
for i in 0...scan.pageCount-1 {
      let originalImage = scan.imageOfPage(at: i)
      let fixedImage =  originalImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.7)
      let reloadedImage = UIImage(data: fixedImage!)
      let imagetoshare = [reloadedImage!]
      
      let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imagetoshare, applicationActivities: nil)
      if let popoverController = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController {
      popoverController.sourceView = self.view
      popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
      popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = []
      }
      // exclude some activity types from the list (optional)
      // present the view controller
      self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

the popover controller code was added as iPads have issues with bringing up the share sheet...

**Error Code I when I attempt to save multiple images**

```
2020-10-03 16:17:21.300830+0530 Scan Box[1163:132306] [ShareSheet] connection invalidated
```

In case you wanted to know what the reloadedImage function is:

```
func reloadedImage(_ originalImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {
      guard let imageData = originalImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1),
            let reloadedImage = UIImage(data: imageData) else {
                return originalImage
      }
      return reloadedImage
}
```

EDIT:
I have removed the '-1' from pageCount and I get this error:

```
-[VNDocumentCameraScan imageOfPageAtIndex:]: index (2) beyond bounds (2).'
```

EDIT 2:

```
       var imagetoShare = [UIImage]()
                for i in 0...scan.pageCount-1 {
                    let originalImage = scan.imageOfPage(at: i)
                    let fixedImage =  originalImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.7)
                    
                    let reloadedImage = UIImage(data: fixedImage!)
                    imagetoShare.append(reloadedImage!)
                  
                        
                        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imagetoShare, applicationActivities: nil)
                        if let popoverController = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController {
                        popoverController.sourceView = self.view
                          popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
                          popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = []
                            
                      }
                              
                              // exclude some activity types from the list (optional)


                              // present the view controller
                              self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I even tried:

```
imagetoShare: [UIImage] = [UIImage]()
```

but still no luck

After these changes my debugger log shows,

```
2020-10-06 16:02:03.813409+0530 Scan Box[1706:336940] [] [16:02:03.811] SurfacePool_DetachSurface signalled err=-16990 (kFigPhotoError_InvalidParameter) (Surface not found in pool) at /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMedia/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2755.18.2.1.1/Sources/Photo/FigPhotoSurfacePool.c:1118
2020-10-06 16:02:06.469717+0530 Scan Box[1706:336940] [] [16:02:06.470] SurfacePool_DetachSurface signalled err=-16990 (kFigPhotoError_InvalidParameter) (Surface not found in pool) at /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMedia/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2755.18.2.1.1/Sources/Photo/FigPhotoSurfacePool.c:1118
2020-10-06 16:02:09.287991+0530 Scan Box[1706:336940] [Presentation] Attempt to present <UIActivityViewController: 0x102055600> on <UINavigationController: 0x102018e00> (from <Scan_Box.ViewController: 0x102019400>) while a presentation is in progress.
2020-10-06 16:02:09.290234+0530 Scan Box[1706:336940] [Presentation] Attempt to present <UIActivityViewController: 0x101a0f200> on <UINavigationController: 0x102018e00> (from <Scan_Box.ViewController: 0x102019400>) while a presentation is in progress.
2020-10-06 16:02:09.292873+0530 Scan Box[1706:337619] [ShareSheet] connection invalidated
2020-10-06 16:02:09.294701+0530 Scan Box[1706:338340] [ShareSheet] connection invalidated
2020-10-06 16:02:15.780167+0530 Scan Box[1706:338348] [ShareSheet] connection invalidated
```

Please help me resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a bunch of UIActivityViewController to show inside your loop from your code so only first of them will be shown because next are skipped.
You should create array of images to share first and then show the controller with this array.

```
// Prepare array of images to share
var images = [UIImage]()
for i in 0...scan.pageCount-1 {
    ...
    images.append(reloadedImage!)
}
// Create and present single activity controller
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: images, applicationActivities: nil)
...
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: No it still doesn't work :( Check my edit for the debugger log.

Comment: I have the same issue, please give more suggestions that may help.

Comment: @Manav103 just move out creation and presenting your UIActivityViewController from the loop.

Comment: Thanks @iUrii a lot this really helped me. Such a simple fix!